# How can two applications exchange heart beat all the time using java or spring framework?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, health-monitoring

I have two instances of my application running. There is a requirement in my project that one instance of app should check heart beat. Both should exchange hear beat all the time. How is this possible in java our using Spring framework ?

Comment: One way to do it is to create a REST API say `/heartbeat` on both applications. This API is a GET API and just returns Status OK. After that both applications can call the `/heartbeat` API at an interval of say 5 minutes (you can make this configurable). If the application gets an OK for the `/heartbeat` API then you know its fine. This should be do-able in Java and with Spring.

Comment: "heartbeat spring java" is a good start for a web search. What have you researched so far?

Answer (score 1):

One solution, certainly not the only solution, would be to...

Have the application include an embedded JMS broker (something like ActiveMQ).
Application instances could connect and listen to a topic that the application publishes heartbeat messages to.  Each instance having its own broker (and topic) to which clients can connect/subscribe.

- Instance 1 subscribes to heartbeats from Instance 2.
- Instance 2 subscribes to heartbeats from Instance 1.